# Pesquisa invertida no Select2 sem utilizar Ajax

Tags: jquery-select2

No DataTables.js a pesquisa funciona desta maneira:

Nome do Produto: `Meias Vermelhas`

A busca retorna o item se você digitar: `Vermelhas Meias`

Como ter a mesma eficiência nas buscas do Select2?

Ref: https://select2.org/searching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No [Select2](https://select2.org/) este recurso não existe nativamente e não tive resultados fazendo manualmente, apesar de conseguir, a performance não ficou legal.

Ao insistir nas buscas, encontrei uma alternativa que soluciona o problema nativamente, é mais leve e resolveu tudo, o [selectize.js](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js)

Para entender um exemplo do resultado, veja abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qualquer termo digitado será contemplado pelo search do select, independente da ordem das palavras. Isso acontece localmente, dentro dos elementos do select, sem a necessidade de uma consulta ajax e o backend para tratar.